# Access Denied while running datadog commands

Tags: windows-10, datadog

I installed datadog agent locally on my windows 10  machine. By default it stored data in ProgramData folder in C drive. It does not give option to select different drive while installation. Now when I run any command, it gives me below error. Can we edit permissions to it allow access to ProgramData folder.

```
C:\Program Files\Datadog\Datadog Agent\embedded>agent.exe status
Getting the status from the agent.

Error: unable to access authentication token: open C:\ProgramData\Datadog\auth_token: Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed it as "Run with Admin rights" and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to manually give the `ddagentuser` account read access to the file

> C:\ProgramData\Datadog\auth_token